# pandoc-citeproc.exe: could not find locale data for DE-

Tags: markdown, pandoc, bibtex

When trying to convert a .md file into .pdf, using pandoc:

```
pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc input.md -s -o output.pdf
```

it throws me an error:

```
pandoc-citeproc.exe: could not find locale data for DE-
pandoc.exe: Error running pandoc-citeproc
Filter returned error status 1
```

I really have no clue how pandoc and pandoc-citeproc are working and therefore no idea how to locate the problem. So any help is appreciated.

I am using: Windows 7 - pandoc 1.17.0.2 - pandoc-citeproc 0.9.1.1

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that the problem was related to my Windows Environment Variables. I followed the recommendations here and it works just fine since then:

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2838